# Equivalence of the Cylinder and Euclidean Space

Tags: metric-spaces, curvature

The cylinder is a smooth surface with zero Gaussian curvature and so can be flattened down into a plane with no distortion of distances.

Does this mean that Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^2$ and the cylinder $S^{1} \times \mathbb{R} $ are equivalent as metric spaces equipped with the same distance function?  Also, what is the radius of this cylinder obtained from the general space $\mathbb{E}^2$?

Comment: a  half of the cylinder can be flattened without distorting distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaussian curvature is a local property... having zero Gaussian curvature means that sufficiently small neighborhoods of each point can be flattened faithfully into the plane.  Certainly the Euclidean plane and the cylinder are not *globally* equivalent, even topologically, let alone as metric spaces.  For instance, note that there are closed geodesic curves on the cylinder but not in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

They share the same first fundamental theorem. The plane and cylinder are isometrically equivalent with corresponding  mappable regions. Isometry is bending and preserves all parameters  that are  functions of common Christoffel symbols.

The second fundamental form is different... and normal curvature of lines changes in bending..